# Cannot see long-term backup files for Azure SQL

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

If I select to restore my Azure SQL database, I can choose from a large number of long-term backup files.

However, I just want to download those files locally.

I cannot see where I can access these files.

The Azure docs suggest that I click on the 'Manage Backups' link.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-long-term-backup-retention-configure

I cannot see this link though.

Has anyone any idea where I can access these files?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot restore those backup files to a local computer because this is a service managed by Azure.

What you can do is restore to a point-in-time which will create a new database, then export that database as bacpac to your local computer, and remove the newly created database once is no longer needed.

```
SqlPackage /Action:Export /SourceServerName:SampleSQLServer.sample.net,1433 /SourceDatabaseName:RestoredDatabase /TargetFile:"F:\Temp\RestoredDatabase.bacpac"
```